# Extract part of an object to an array

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have an array of hundreds of objects like the following:

```
{
    "id" : 893,
    ....
    "responsable" : {
        "id" : 792,
        "version" : 13,
        "username" : "xxxxx@mail.es",
        "nombre" : "Peter",
        "apellido1" : "Murphy",
        "apellido2" : "XXX"
   }
}
```

Within my object I have another object that is "responsable". Need to get an array of these objects, but only once each (remove repeated)

Comment: What's the criteria for removing duplicates? How do you distinguish two objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to summarise your data to an object. And use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array.

This example will extract all responsables and remove duplicates based on `responsable.id`

```js
let arr = [
{"id": 893,"responsable": {"id": 792,"version": 13,"username": "xxxxx@mail.es","nombre": "John","apellido1": "Murphy","apellido2": "XXX"}},
{"id": 894,"responsable": {"id": 793,"version": 13,"username": "xxxxx@mail.es","nombre": "Peter","apellido1": "Murphy","apellido2": "XXX"}},
{"id": 895,"responsable": {"id": 792,"version": 13,"username": "xxxxx@mail.es","nombre": "John","apellido1": "Murphy","apellido2": "XXX"}},
{"id": 896,"responsable": {"id": 794,"version": 13,"username": "xxxxx@mail.es","nombre": "Paul","apellido1": "Murphy","apellido2": "XXX"}}
];

let responsable = Object.values(arr.reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {[v.responsable.id]: v.responsable}), {}));

console.log(responsable);
```